# Использование using в внутритекстовом коде на странице ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#, веб-программирование

Искал в Интернете, но ответа на свой вопрос не нашел. Хотя подозреваю, что это основы основ.

Если использовать внутритекстовую модель кода на странице ASP.NET, как использовать using?
Среда VS выдает ошибку на using на примере ниже. Не хочется каждый раз использовать полное имя, вроде System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.

Пример:

```
...
<script>
using System.Data.SqlClient;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    ...
} 
</script>
...
<html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
```